# In c or c++ how can i give input to a program without enter or space

Tags: c++, c

i want to write a program in which i will give the input as 109876543 and the program will calculate the sum by adding each digit in the given input (1+0+9+8+7+6+5+4+3). so how to separate these digit and add them and which data type to choose to store this input??

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) (you might also like the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)).
On Windows there's the equivalent [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/).

Store the input in an array of character (not necessarily a string).

Answer (score 1):

[for C]

Go for unbuffered I/O:

- Define an `int` to hold the sum and initialise it to `0`.
- Use `select()` to test if there is something to read from `fileno(stdin)`.
- Use `read()` to read in exactly one `char`.
- Use `isdigit()` to test whether it's a number and if substract `48` and add the result to the sum.
- Start over.

Comment: Boost.ASIO is more portable than `select`.

Comment: If you write your solution in such a detailed fashion, add an ending condition.